# Magento DHL module, what it's supposed to do?

Tags: magento, e-commerce, magento-1.7

Should be an easy-to-find info, but I wasn't able to find any doc page explaining what the DHL module can do and what cannot. Specifically:

- can automatically create the shipment? (I mean, in such a way that whenever an order is placed - w-and ithout any action by me - someone at DHL will be notified that there's a box to be picked up at my company to be shipped...)
- can automatically create the tracking number and send it - via email - to the customer

or all it can do is just getting quotes?

Answer (score 1):

No, and No.  What it does do is allow for you to get, display, and record rates for the various shipping options.

Comment: thanks. is there any official and/or detailed documentation of the module?

Comment: Yes.  The Official Magento User's Guide has a somewhat detail explanation on the DHL shipping configuration options under 'Shipping'. http://www.magentocommerce.com/resources/magento-user-guide

Comment: In Magento_Community_1-7_User_Guide.pdf shipping starts on page 145 (page 155 in PDF). But they do not explain the DHL module.